# Matching intent in DialogFlow on longer speech section

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm using the phone integration in DialogFlow.
I have a scenario where there is a continuous speech for about 40-50 seconds.

I'm trying to match an intent of one sentence (5 to 7 words) inside this speech section. It looks like DialogFlow will not try to match the intent until it gets a reasonable pause in the speech.

Is there a way to get a more "real time" response?
Or to set the silence detection that breaks between intent recognitions to a smaller value?
Any other strategy?